# Add filename to access table while importing csv file

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have multiple csv files in multiple folders all in one master folder on drive C:. Some files are updated each day. If a file has an update, I need to load the new daily data into an access table including the file name.   The script so far imports all data from all csv files. Then it adds the file name in a new record. I need the file name added to all records.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Script:

Sub Import_multiple_csv_files()

```
Const strPath As String = "C:\text1\" 'Directory Path
Dim strFile As String 'Filename
Dim strFileList() As String 'File  Array
Dim intFile As Integer 'File Number
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
 'Loop through the folder & build file list
strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.csv")
While strFile <> ""
     'add files to the list
    intFile = intFile + 1
    ReDim Preserve strFileList(1 To intFile)
    strFileList(intFile) = strFile
    strFile = Dir()
Wend
 'see if any files were found
If intFile = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No files found"
    Exit Sub
End If
 'cycle through the list of files &  import to Access
 'creating a new table called MyTable

For intFile = 1 To UBound(strFileList)

DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelimi, , _
    "Test", strPath & strFileList(intFile)
    ‘add file name to record
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Test")
    rs.AddNew
    rs.Fields("Com").Value = Dir(strPath & "*")
    rs.Update
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing


Next

MsgBox UBound(strFileList) & " Files were Imported"
```

End Sub

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure what the question is, but if you're trying to update the filename in the records you've just imported you can do with a simple update statement:

```
UPDATE Test SET Com='MyFileName' WHERE Com IS NULL OR Com=''
```

Here I'm assuming that the field will be null or an empty string but you can replace this with your own criteria if this is incorrect. You can use [DoCmd.RunSQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff194626.aspx) to do this.

If I am misunderstanding the problem then please update your question to make it clearer.

Comment: Hi,Tks for your advice. In the fro loop starting 'For intFile = 1 To UBound(strFileList)' as each record is placed in the access table, I want the file name placed into table column 'com'. Will your suggestion work within this loop?

Comment: Yes, you want the filename saved with each imported record. TransferText will load the whole file (so multiple records) in one go. You then need to update those records with the filename. Call the UPDATE statement in the loop and make sure that the WHERE clause only picks up the latest records otherwise you will update previous records as well. With the recordset code you have used you are adding another new record, not updating existing records. You can do what you want in a recordset but the one-line DoCmd.RunSQL statement will be simpler.

Comment: `CurrentDB.Execute SQLString, dbFailOnError` will skip the warnings that you get with `DoCmd.RunSQL` and if you assign CurrentDB to a database object first, and use that, you can get the `RecordsAffected, which may be useful.`

Comment: @Remou, good point and a better solution. Sid - do what he said.

Comment: Hi, progress... The script now loads all the fields in column 'com'  with the text text 'myfile'. How do I get the filename where the data came from into the field? I tried strFile with and without quotes but this did not work. Many tks in advance.

Comment: For example, in the loop 'While strFile<>' 2 files are found each with 2 lines of data, four rows should appear in the table, row 1 & 2  with the first file name in column com and row 3 & 4 with the second filename in column com. I did not implement the suggestion from Remou yet as I tried and did not get it to work.

Comment: You need 3 quotes (or might be four, can't remember) on each side: "SETCom='''" & MyFileName & "''' WHERE....

Comment: Somehow in the SQL, SET Com = "" is not able to refer to the name of the file where the data is?

Comment: Hi, Many thanks for your help. Above you mention I need 3 quotes around &MyFileName&  is 'MyFileName' script that will extract the file name from the path or just a literal reference to the file name? If it a literal reference then I need to identify in the script where the file name is defined and how to code it into the sql so it is inserted into the table.

Comment: Hi Simon and @Remou , Thanks for all your patience. I have hardly programmed or used VBA and am a rank beginner so I appreciate your support.   In the following 2 posts are the (1) updated code and (2)output  I still cant get the file name in column com but do get the string in quotes. Any ideas how to get the actual filename in column com? many thanks. Sub Import_multiple_csv_files()

Comment: I cannot fit the code and output into a comment box so I will start another question called "File name into access table"

Comment: MyFileName was just an example I used, you need to replace this with the actual filename variable you are using - strFileList(intFile) by the look of it.